# AWS CDK How can I add an existing usage plan to api stage

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, infrastructure-as-code

CDK documentation define that I can import an external usage plan through the static function named [`fromUsagePlanId`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.UsagePlan.html#static-fromwbrusagewbrplanwbridscope-id-usageplanid) but this returns an `Interface IUsagePlan` but which interface doesn't have the method `addApiStage` to attach my Api and its stage.

my snippet code:

```
import * as apigateway from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway';


export class CdkApiGwTemplateStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);


    const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this,`${domain.toLowerCase()}-${subDomain.toLowerCase()}`,
      {
        restApiName: `${domain.toLowerCase()}-${subDomain.toLowerCase()}`,
        description: apiDescription,
        binaryMediaTypes: binaryMediaTypes,
        deployOptions: {
          accessLogDestination: new LogGroupLogDestination(logGroup),
          loggingLevel:
            cloudwatchLoggingLevel.toUpperCase() as MethodLoggingLevel,
          stageName: environment.toLowerCase(),
          variables: variables,
        },
      }
    );

    const key = api.addApiKey('ApiKey', {
      apiKeyName: apikeyName,
      description: apiKeyDescription,
    });

    const plan = apigateway.UsagePlan.fromUsagePlanId(this, 'getExternalUsagePlan', usagePlanId);

    plan.addApiKey(key);
```

I tried to search a cfn level 1 of cloudformation to do that, but I couldn't find out. How can I use method `addApiStage` of the constructor `UsagePlan` with the interface `IUsagePlan` or some idea of how can I add mi api to Usage plan existing?

Comment: You can get a [read-only reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resources_external) to, but not modify, existing resources external to your CDK app.

Comment: @fedonev - I've found this isn't wholly true, I've implemented CDK code which specifically prevents modifications to an imported role when deploying CodePipeline constructs. Also I think this 'read-only' intent is overly restrictive - if I have a 'base' stack which provides resources for a child stack then it can be necessary for the child to modify 'parent' resources - adding an API stage to a shared usage plan is a great example. If child stacks can't exist without the parent then it makes good sense for those to be able to fully utilise the parent's resources.

Answer (score 3):

So after giving up on finding ad-hoc solution I wrote my own construct.
It's a custom construct using lambda resource provider (the lambda manages the resource lifecycle)
And many thanks to Jeffb4 for this helpful repo: https://github.com/stelligent/cloudformation-custom-resources/blob/master/lambda/python/customresource.py

The code of using it:

```py
usage_plan_id = "usage_id_here"
bind_usage_plan = BindUsagePlanConstruct(
    self, "BindUsagePlan", usage_plan_id, self.rest_api
)  # self.rest_api is of type apigateway.RestApi
bind_usage_plan.node.add_dependency(self.rest_api)
```

The construct code:

```py
from os import path
from aws_cdk import CustomResource, aws_lambda, RemovalPolicy, Duration, aws_iam
from aws_cdk import aws_logs
from aws_cdk.custom_resources import Provider
from constructs import Construct


class BindUsagePlanConstruct(Construct):
    def __init__(
        self, scope: Construct, _id: str, usage_plan_id: str, rest_api
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, _id)
        self._scope = scope._scope
        event_handler = self._create_lambda_function()
        provider = Provider(
            scope=self,
            id=f"{_id}Provider",
            on_event_handler=event_handler,
            log_retention=aws_logs.RetentionDays.ONE_DAY,
        )
        CustomResource(
            scope=self,
            id=f"{_id}UsagePlanBind",
            service_token=provider.service_token,
            removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
            resource_type="Custom::UsagePlanBind",
            properties={
                "usage_plan_id": usage_plan_id,
                "api_gw_id": f"{rest_api.rest_api_id}",
                "api_gw_stage": f"{rest_api.deployment_stage.stage_name}",
            },
        )

    def _create_lambda_function(self):
        with open(
            path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "bind_usage_plan_lambda.py")
        ) as file:
            code = file.read()
        return aws_lambda.Function(
            self,
            f"{id}EventHandler",
            runtime=aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_12,
            handler="index.on_event",
            code=aws_lambda.Code.from_inline(code),
            timeout=Duration.minutes(15),
            initial_policy=[
                aws_iam.PolicyStatement(
                    actions=[
                        "apigateway:GET",
                        "apigateway:POST",
                        "apigateway:DELETE",
                        "apigateway:PATCH",
                    ],
                    resources=[
                        f"arn:aws:apigateway:{self._scope.region}::/usageplans/*",
                        f"arn:aws:apigateway:{self._scope.region}::/usageplans/*/apiStages/*:prod",
                        f"arn:aws:apigateway:{self._scope.region}::/restapis/*",
                    ],
                )
            ],
        )
```

And here is the lambda code:

```py
import logging
from hashlib import sha224

LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)
import boto3

client = boto3.client("apigateway")


def on_event(event, context):
    request_type = event["RequestType"]
    if request_type == "Create":
        return on_create(event, context)
    if request_type == "Update":
        return on_update(event, context)
    if request_type == "Delete":
        return on_delete(event, context)
    raise Exception("Invalid request type: %s" % request_type)


def on_create(event, context):
    try:
        return _assign_usage_plan_if_not_assigned(event, context)
    except Exception as err:
        LOGGER.error(f"Error occurred while assigning usage plan: {err}")
        return _build_response(event, context, "FAILED", {"error": str(err)})


def on_update(event, context):
    try:
        old_properties = event["OldResourceProperties"]
        old_api_gw_id = old_properties["api_gw_id"]
        old_api_gw_stage = old_properties["api_gw_stage"]
        old_usage_plan_id = old_properties["usage_plan_id"]
        if _is_usage_plan_exists(old_usage_plan_id) and _is_usage_plan_assigned(
            old_usage_plan_id, old_api_gw_id
        ):
            _remove_usage_plan_assignment(
                old_usage_plan_id, old_api_gw_id, old_api_gw_stage
            )
        return _assign_usage_plan_if_not_assigned(event, context)
    except Exception as err:
        LOGGER.error(f"Error occurred while assigning usage plan: {err}")
        return _build_response(event, context, "FAILED", {"error": str(err)})


def on_delete(event, context):
    props = event["ResourceProperties"]
    LOGGER.info(f"Start assigning usage plan with props {props}")
    api_gw_id = props["api_gw_id"]
    api_gw_stage = props["api_gw_stage"]
    usage_plan_id = props["usage_plan_id"]
    if not _is_usage_plan_exists(usage_plan_id) or not _is_usage_plan_assigned(
        usage_plan_id, api_gw_id
    ):
        return _build_response(
            event, context, "SUCCESS", {"message": "Usage plan already unassigned"}
        )
    try:
        _remove_usage_plan_assignment(usage_plan_id, api_gw_id, api_gw_stage)
    except Exception as err:
        return _build_response(event, context, "FAILED", {"error": str(err)})
    return _build_response(event, context, "SUCCESS")


def _build_response(event, context, response_status: str, response_data: object = None):
    if response_data is None:
        response_data = {}
    physical_resource_id = event.get(
        "PhysicalResourceId", sha224(context.log_stream_name.encode()).hexdigest()
    )  # unique value
    return {
        "Status": response_status,
        "Reason": "See the details in CloudWatch Log Stream: "
        + context.log_stream_name,
        "PhysicalResourceId": physical_resource_id,
        "StackId": event["StackId"],
        "RequestId": event["RequestId"],
        "LogicalResourceId": event["LogicalResourceId"],
        "Data": response_data,
    }


def _is_usage_plan_assigned(usage_plan_id: str, api_gw_id: str):
    LOGGER.info(
        f"Checking if usage plan {usage_plan_id} is assigned to api gw {api_gw_id}"
    )
    response = client.get_usage_plan(
        usagePlanId=usage_plan_id,
    )
    api_stages = response["apiStages"]
    for api_stage in api_stages:
        if api_stage["apiId"] == api_gw_id:
            return True
    return False


def _is_usage_plan_exists(usage_plan_id: str):
    LOGGER.info(f"Checking if usage plan {usage_plan_id} exists")
    try:
        client.get_usage_plan(
            usagePlanId=usage_plan_id,
        )
        return True
    except client.exceptions.NotFoundException:
        return False


def _assign_usage_plan_if_not_assigned(event, context):
    props = event["ResourceProperties"]
    LOGGER.info(f"Start assigning usage plan with props {props}")
    api_gw_id = props["api_gw_id"]
    api_gw_stage = props["api_gw_stage"]
    usage_plan_id = props["usage_plan_id"]
    if _is_usage_plan_assigned(usage_plan_id, api_gw_id):
        return _build_response(
            event, context, "SUCCESS", {"message": "Usage plan already assigned"}
        )
    client.update_usage_plan(
        usagePlanId=usage_plan_id,
        patchOperations=[
            {
                "op": "add",
                "path": "/apiStages",
                "value": f"{api_gw_id}:{api_gw_stage}",
            }
        ],
    )
    LOGGER.info("Usage plan assigned")
    return _build_response(event, context, "SUCCESS")


def _remove_usage_plan_assignment(
    usage_plan_id: str, api_gw_id: str, api_gw_stage: str
):
    client.update_usage_plan(
        usagePlanId=usage_plan_id,
        patchOperations=[
            {
                "op": "remove",
                "path": "/apiStages",
                "value": f"{api_gw_id}:{api_gw_stage}",
            }
        ],
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can achieve this, dependent on how the resources were created in the first place (Click-ops or via CloudFormation).

- You can use the recently released IaC Generator to generate CloudFormation and CDK from existing resources, see https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2024/02/aws-cloudformation-templates-cdk-apps-minutes/ and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/generate-IaC.html
- You can use CDK migrate to bring CloudFormation resources into your CDK stacks. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/migrate.html for details.

Comment: The usage plan is Iac managed. but by a different stack (in different repository).
When trying to get the resource by ID to my CDK I get an 'IUsagePlan' object which not allowing me to attach an api-gw. the way to fix this is by creating a custom resource